# Downsample a double array to another length

Tags: c#, .net, math, interpolation

I have a data source that provides many (4096) double values in an array. These are measured with high resolution and are the result of a FFT. For visualisation purposes, they need to be reduced. (Reapplying the FFT on the raw signal is not possible here.) I could simply average each *n* samples and have a resulting array of *length* / *n* values. To allow more flexible selection of the number of resulting values, I need interpolation, though.

I've looked up some basic information about this on Wikipedia. I am already familiar with 2D downsampling/interpolation from a user prespective in raster image editors. Now I need this in 1D in C# code. Think of it as changing (reducing) the raster image size of a 1D barcode image, or resampling an audio wave file.

One library I've found recommended is Math.NET Numerics. This is already used for other tasks in my application, so I could easily use that. There's the `CubicSpline` class in there but I have  no idea how to use it.

**Q:** What would be an approach to reduce the number of samples in a `double[]` to an arbitrary number using interpolation?

I'm not interested in finding a single double value between two others. I need to combine multiple source values into each a single output value, while not losing any information (single frequency bins with an extreme level) at the boundaries of the groups, and without aliasing effects or rounding because of different group sizes if the numbers aren't divisible.

Maybe the use of bitmap image functions and a 1*n bitmap size is a good solution instead of dealing with the math directly? This would involve a lot of data conversion, though, which reduces performance and probably also precision. Or some library from the autio processing field?

Comment: There are a great many ways to downsample data, and the best way often depends on the characteristics of the data you're downsampling. However, the ["Largest Triangle Three Bucket"](https://skemman.is/handle/1946/15343) algorithm is generally effective for downsampling for display. See [here](https://gist.github.com/adrianseeley/264417d295ccd006e7fd) for a sample implementation - but there are others you can google for.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Thank you, this paper is very theoretical and I cannot apply it in code. I have edited my question to better explain what I'm doing.

Comment: I misread your comment and found that the sample implementation you gave provides reasonable results.

Comment: I would probably use `double` rather than `float` in the implementation, mind. I guess you might have already changed that.